# Path to file invalid

Tags: mono

I'm trying to start a program with mono.  I'm typing :

`mono "home/shopy/smath_studio/smath/smath.exe"`

I'm getting

```
Cannot open assembly 'home/shopy/smath_studio/smath/smath.exe': No such file or directory.
```

What am i doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

may be you just missed the leading "/"?

try

```
mono "/home/shopy/smath_studio/smath/smath.exe"
```

Comment: How silly of me, you were correct sir, thank you.

Comment: @Shopy : Take the time to read about [Tab Completion](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Command-line_completion). It is installed by default in Ubuntu. This way you will avoid such mistakes in future.